# Confused With Websocket Connections

Tags: java, javascript, json, websocket, connection

Here is what the request looks like in the browser:

```
{
    "method": "joinChannel",
    "params": {
        "channel": "brobq",
        "name": "GrillBot",
        "token": "xxx",
        "isAdmin": false
    }
}
```

From what I can tell, that is just simple JSON. where "xxx" is my api token.

I am wondering how I would be able to go about creating a connection in either Java or Javascript that would allow me to connect to the chat and read it in the program (I am trying to make a chat bot). I have made one for an IRC chat server before so I get the basic commands and things like that. I am just having a hard time figuring out how to connect to the Websocket server initially. The server requires you to log in with the name and token and connects you to a channel.

If you would like to see for yourself, here is the http link: http://hitbox.tv/BroBQ